# Flutter / Dart :upload image to twitter api using twitter api with multi_image_picker

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, twitter

I hope you are well.
Since just now, I can't publish a tweet with an image using the Twitter API.

The following error: `{"errors":[{"code":32, "message": "Could not authenticate you."}]}`.

And I can't put my finger on what's wrong.

Here's how I upload the image (media)

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert' as convert;

    Future<void> uploadMedia(
              List<List<int>> imagesData, String authorizationHeader) async {
            var mediaIds = <String>[];
            
            for (var imageData in imagesData) {
              final baseURL =
                  Uri.parse('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json');
              final header = {Fields.authorization.toLowerCase(): authorizationHeader};
              final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', baseURL);
        
              http.MultipartFile multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                'media', //the name of media parameter
                imageData,
              );
        
              request.headers.addAll(header);
              request.files.add(multipartFile);
        
              var response = await request.send();
              response.stream.transform(convert.utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
                print('API RESPONSE : $value');
              });
        
            }

          }
```

Twitter api documentation to [UPLOAD MEDIA](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload)

multi_image_picker documentation to [upload image to an API](https://sh1d0w.github.io/multi_image_picker/#/upload)

THANKS

Comment: Try to print in a console your request and send it again from computer for check response state.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're getting an authentication error of 32.

As per Twitter [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting#:%7E:text=Code%2032%20%2D%20Could%20not%20authenticate%20you&text=This%20is%20not%20an%20Account,for%20the%20Account%20Activity%20API.), it would mean that something is either malformed in the request, headers, authorization, or the URI (as defined in their documentation).

Make sure your authentication steps are right, and that you have provided the correct permissions for your access tokens.